# Remotely shutdown a MySQL server

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL 5.0.27 running on a Linux server. It is consuming too many resources (it is running about 80 tasks loading a database). I am unable to log into the server to reduce the number of tasks because SSH, while accepting a password, will time out while requesting a new channel because of the system load.

Can I remotely send a shutdown command to the server? It is possible from another server to either use `mysql` or `mysqladmin` with a `-h` option or use MySQL workbench to shut the server down gracefully?

If I reboot the server I will need to repair two large tables (>200m records) which takes hours. I'd like to avoid this option.

Answer (score 2):

You can send commands via ssh (that is you don't have to actually log in and run the command):

```
ssh user@host 'mysqladmin shutdown'
```

Comment: I can actually connect to the server using mysql -h IPADDR. But mysqladmin -h IPADDR just outputs the usage listing. It doesn't recognize the -h (or --host=IPADDR) command.

Comment: `mysqladmin -h IPADDR` just outputs the usage listing, yes, but not because it doesn't recognize --host.  The problem is, `mysqladmin` requires an *actual command to be specified* such as `shutdown` or `status` -- you can't just type "mysqladmin" (with or without options) and omit the actual thing you want `mysqladmin` to do.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
mysqladmin shutdown
```

More at [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqladmin.html)

Comment: it would work if I could log into the box.

Comment: oh yeah,my bad.You can connect using MySQL bench ? if so,you can stop the server for there. '-h' should work! well you are sure you have the remote access right?

Comment: see my last comment on the answer above. Mysqladmin -h is ignoring the command. I can connect using mysql bench, but remote access is SSH based and SSH can't connect. We're talking rock and hard place here.

Comment: SSH can't connect .hmm, Sorry dude seems like major prob then I thought ! Lets hope some one solves this :) Good luck!